# Restricting functions that can be passed to another function in C++

Tags: c++, static, enums

I have a class containing several very similar functions and a couple other functions that take those interchangeably functions as input.

A simpler example:

```
class functions{
      public:
           int a();
           int b();
           int F(int (*f)() ); //f can only be a() or b()
};
```

Before I put them in a class, I had something like

```
if(f!=a || f!=b) cout<<"error";
```

With the class, it seems to just get more complicated, since I believe I now need to pass a class instance or something to get rid of my `error: invalid use of member function`

I have just started to learn about enumerated lists, and it seems like that would do the job if I was dealing with normal variables.  Can I create an enum of functions?

What is the best way to restrict functions that can be passed to another function?

---

I'm pursuing the static cast method, but still needing help with int F( int(*f)() );

```
int functions::F(int (functions::*f)() )
{
    if(f==functions::a)  
        //gives  error: invalid operands of types 'int (functions::*)()' 
           //  and 'int (int(*)()' to binary operator =='

    int x=f();
        //gives error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member
          //function in  'f(...)' 

    int y=(functions.*f)();
         //gives error: expected primary-expression before ‘.*’ token

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your original code was really `f != &a`, only the address-of was implicit.  Well, there's no implicit address for member functions, you really to need to say `&functions::a`.  Later to call it you probably want to say `(this->*f)()`

Comment: what does "implicit address for member functions" mean?

Comment: It means you can't leave out the & if what you want is a pointer to member. And you can't leave out the * when using a pointer to member.

Comment: even with (f==&functions::a), I still get invalid operands, though (this->*f)() fixes my other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to achieve:
I'd say largely that this sort of restriction is best validated by code review rather than coding...

The other solution is to not use that construct at all, and making a `Fa()` and `Fb()` function that calls the (private) `a()` and `b()` member functions.

And the remainder of the question is "how do I call a member function of a class" -the answer to which depends highly on whether `Functions` has member variables that are used in `a()` and `b()` or not. If there are no member functions, then declaring the `a()` and `b()` members as `static` will work. On the other hand, if you want to use a "member function pointer", the syntax is `int (Functions::*f)` and `&Functions::a` respectively, and the call has to be made using an instance of `Functions`. so if we have `Functions fun`, you'd do `fun.*f()`. Or `(*this).*f()`, insice `F()`.

Comment: do you know a good tutorial on how I could implement making a() and b() static, passing them, and then using them in my code?  Google seems to be giving me a lot of results about Non-static member functions, but not much help on static.  I'm getting a lot of error messages I can't interpret 'error: cannot convert ‘double(double (*)(double), int, double, double, bool)’ to ‘double (Integrators::*)(double (*)(double), int, double, double, bool)’ in assignment
  else if(Meth=Integrators::Midp)' and 'error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘Meth (...)’

Comment: Just stick "satic" in front of the name, and use it like `Functions::a` and `Functions::b`.

Answer (score 0):

You may wrap the accepted function in a class:

```
#include <iostream>

class Functions
{
    public:
    int a() { return 0; }
    int b() { return 1; }
};

class Accept
{
    public:
    typedef int (Functions::*AcceptFunction)();
    int apply(Functions& object,  AcceptFunction function) {
        return (object.*function)();
    }
};


int main()
{
    Functions functions;
    Accept accept;
    std::cout << accept.apply(functions, &Functions::b) << std::endl;
}
```

(Feel free to bundle it by making Functions a nested class in Accept)